# Are companions able to teleport to the player?

Tags: kingdom-hearts

Since I started playing KH1 I noticed that the companions are actually pretty good about following you and keeping up. I was surprised, because I noticed (when looking at them anyway) they would climb over obstacles, jump, swim, or whatever the environment happens to be, since the game is so old (2002 I think) I figured that there the my AI counterparts would have some path finding problems, but thankfully I was incorrect..

I know that if you enter through a door (or a loading point) the companion(s) will be with you no matter what, I assume this is to avoid issues. I also noticed that companions will not use vines in the Jungle either.

Please include the following information:

- Are companions able teleport to the player
- Assuming the question above is yes, how far away do you need to be for them to teleport?
- Will companions try to manually get to to you, before attempting to teleport?
- Will the companions teleport while you can see them or will they attempt to be discrete?

6/27/2013 @6:41PM - I also think it is worth noting that there isn't really any documentation on their AI except some vague descriptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. They don't teleport unless, like you said, you go through a door. I've been missing a companion from time to time, but they always end up doing a super jump to get where I am, or just wait below me if they've fallen, for example.

I know this, because I've had companions stuck behind or under things, and I've had to go on without them for a little while. But whenever a companion is returning to me, they're running up, not just magically appearing, and I see them come out from behind whatever they're behind. Some pretty good path-finding AI if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

Companions can teleport to the player. Any teleport will allow the companion to teleport. The companions will try to manually get to you. If they can't get to you within 5 seconds they will teleport and they will teleport whether or not you can see them or not.